# Маска ввода и ограничение значений

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Есть задача сделать ввод фамилии - как ограничить пользователю ввод цифр точек и так далее. Использовать маску?

Comment: Самый лучший способ: позволить пользователю вводить что угодно. А валидацию проводить после потери фокуса контролом. Потому что юзер может захотеть вставить (Ctrl+V) скопированный откуда-то текст, при этом могут быть захвачены другие символы, по крайней мере пробелы.

Comment: Научитесь делать привязки, научитесь использовать XAML, это основа основ любого WPF проекта. У вас не должно быть по хорошему событий, не должно быть `x:Name`, не должно быть вообще данных в UI. Сам ваш код должен быть таким, будто вы написали консольный проект, у которого вообще нет UI, вот вы удаляете окно полностью - ваш проект продолжает работать, вот тогда у вас будет WPF. Валидация чего либо, это уровень UI, делается через [ValidationRule](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/14.php) (или `IDataErrorInfo`), без каких либо событий, ограничений, и прочего.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

запрет всего, кроме букв:

```
    string Symbol = e.KeyChar.ToString();

    if (!Regex.Match(Symbol, @"[а-яА-Я]|[a-zA-Z]").Success)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

добавить в событие TextBox1_KeyPress. никаких других условий не нужно

Comment: можно ли как то сделать без вызова событий?

Comment: `Regex.IsMatch` есть еще